# X86 IDIV sign of remainder depends on sign of dividend for 8/-3 and -8/3?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, integer-division, emu8086

Can anyone explain for me why the sign of the remainder is different in these cases? Is this an emulator bug or do real CPUs do this, too?

[image]

```
8 / -3 : quotient(AL) = -2 remainder(AH) =  2
-8 / 3 : quotient(AL) = -2 remainder(AH) = -2
```

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/idiv

Comment: is this a programming problem?

Comment: @AkberIqbal : Yes, this is an assembly language programming question.

Answer (score 5):

It is supposed to work that way, though it is tricky to find out by reading the documentation:

> Non-integral results are truncated (chopped) towards 0.

Combined with the "division law" X = dq + r (the dividend is the divisor times the quotient plus the remainder), we find that therefore the remainder r = X - d truncate(X / d)

This shows that the remainder depends on the sign of the dividend, but not on the sign of the divisor.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, very easy to understand!